# image downloaded from server on android returning null

Tags: android, image, null, download

I want to download an image from server, I am able to download some images but not all, I dont understand why. I have search all over the net but did not find any solution. my code is

```
HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
drawable= Drawable.createFromStream(conn.getInputStream(), "");
```

I have also tried this code :

```
bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL(url).openConnection().getInputStream());
```

nothing seem to work both bitmap and drawable are null.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the return code of the HttpURLConnection by using the [getResponseCode](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getResponseCode%28%29) method? Maybe the resource wasn't found or it contains a redirect.

Comment: no actually its my server only i have uploaded those image. actually some times it works, but very few time only.

Comment: I'd recommend to download the file to the sdcard at first and create an image out of it afterwards. This would help to find the error.

Comment: i checked it its 500kb file but only able to download 50kb file i dont understand what's the problem

Comment: this solved my problem a little bit http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html